# .net Maui Maps - Location with multiple pins data binding issue

Tags: maui

When I try to display multiple pins from a json file onto a map, I get the following error:

> "No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Latitude", or
> mismatching type between value and property.(XFC0009)"

I have confirmed that my service is working and data is coming in. The data types for Latitude and Longitude are doubles. Also, if I hard code the lat and long then it works for that one location, and the data for "Label" and "Address" populate just fine.

```
Model:
public class Incident
{
  ...
  public double Latitude { get; set; }
  public double Longitude { get; set; }
  ...
}

View:
<maps:Map.ItemTemplate\>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Incident"\>
    <maps:Pin Address="{Binding Address}"
              Label="{Binding City}"\>
      <maps:Pin.Location\>
        <sensors:Location Latitude="{Binding Latitude}"
                          Longitude="{Binding Longitude}"\>
        </sensors:Location\>
      </maps:Pin.Location\>
    </maps:Pin\>
  </DataTemplate\>  
</maps:Map.ItemTemplate\>

ViewModel:
public partial class MapPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    [ObservableProperty]
    Incident incident;


    public ObservableCollection<Incident> Incidents { get; } = new();
    readonly IncidentService incidentService;
    readonly IConnectivity connectivity;
    readonly IGeolocation geolocation;


    public MapPageViewModel(IncidentService incidentService, IConnectivity connectivity, IGeolocation geolocation)
    {
        Title = "Map Page";
        this.incidentService = incidentService;
        this.connectivity = connectivity;
                this.geolocation = geolocation;

                GetIncidentsCommand.CanExecute(true);
                GetIncidentsCommand.Execute(true);
                GetIncidentsCommand.CanExecute(false);
         }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetIncidentsAsync()
    {
        if (connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("No Connectivity!",
                $"Please check internet and try again.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            var incidents = await incidentService.GetIncidents();

            if (Incidents.Count > 0)
                Incidents.Clear();

            foreach (var incident in incidents)
                Incidents.Add(incident);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get incidents: {ex.Message}");
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
        }

        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *" if I hard code the lat and long then it works for that one location"* 1) Show the code you used to hardcode one location. Be sure to show EVERY DETAIL that you did differently, in xaml and/or c# 2) Sounds like something is different between the hardcoded value, and the value incoming from the json. 3) Or what you did to "hardocde lat and long" is not the same as displaying a list of Incidents. If you ADD the hardcoded lat/long Incident to the start of the list, does it show correctly? 4) As a sanity check, please add to question the two working declarations (Address, City).

Comment: 5) perhaps string format vs double value. When you hardcoded, was it a string? Maybe change Lat/Long to string, and in input, make sure creating the expected string format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that "Latitude" and "Longitude" as part os sensors:Location are not bindable properties. Maps:Pin instead is looking very specifically for Position which is made up of three components, "Label", "Address", and "Location." The first two are strings and "Location" contains "Latitude" and  "Longitude" values of the type double. Since I am trying to dynamically generate multiple pins, I needed two different data models, one for the data coming in from the database (Incidents) and one for "Positions." I also needed two ObservableCollections, one for Incidents and one for Positions. I then had to populate "Positions" with data from Incidents. Below are the updated Model, View, and ViewModel.

```
Incident Model:
public class Incident
{
    ...
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }
    ...
}

Position Model:
public class Position : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Location _location;

    public string Label { get; }
    public string Description { get; }

    public Location Location
    {
        get => _location;
        set
        {
            if (Location == null || !_location.Equals(value))
            {
                _location = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Location)));
            }
        }
    }

    public Position(string label, string description, Location location)
    {
        Label = label;
        Description = description;
        Location = location;
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}

ViewModel:
public partial class MapPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{


    [ObservableProperty]
    Incident incident;


    public ObservableCollection<Incident> Incidents { get; } = new();
    public ObservableCollection<Position> _positions { get; } = new();

    public IEnumerable Positions => _positions;



    readonly IncidentService incidentService;
    readonly IConnectivity connectivity;
    readonly IGeolocation geolocation;

    public MapPageViewModel(IncidentService incidentService, IConnectivity connectivity, IGeolocation geolocation)
    {
        Title = "Map Page";
        this.incidentService = incidentService;
        this.connectivity = connectivity;
        this.geolocation = geolocation;


        _positions = new ObservableCollection<Position>();


        GetIncidentsCommand.CanExecute(true);
        GetIncidentsCommand.Execute(true);
        GetIncidentsCommand.CanExecute(false);

        
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task GetIncidentsAsync()
    {
        if (connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
        {
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("No Connectivity!",
                $"Please check internet and try again.", "OK");
            return;
        }

        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        try
        {
            IsBusy = true;

            var incidents = await incidentService.GetIncidents();

            if (Incidents.Count > 0)
                Incidents.Clear();

            foreach (var incident in incidents)
            {
                _positions.Add(new Position(incident.City, incident.Address, new Location(incident.Lat, incident.Long)));

            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to get procedures: {ex.Message}");
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Error!", ex.Message, "OK");
        }

        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }

    }
}

View:
<maps:Map x:Name="map"
               ItemsSource="{Binding _positions}"
               IsShowingUser="true">
        <x:Arguments>
            <MapSpan>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <sensors:Location>
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <x:Double>32.318230</x:Double>
                            <x:Double>-86.902298</x:Double>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </sensors:Location>
                    <x:Double>4.00</x:Double>
                    <x:Double>4.00</x:Double>
                </x:Arguments>
            </MapSpan>
        </x:Arguments>
        <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Position">
                <maps:Pin Address="{Binding Description}"
                          Label="{Binding Label}"
                          Location="{Binding Location}">
                    
                                           
                </maps:Pin>
            </DataTemplate>    
        </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:Map>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the step of official doc: [Display a pin collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-7.0#display-a-pin-collection):

```
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps">    
    <Grid>
        ...
        <maps:Map x:Name="map"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Positions}">
            <maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <maps:Pin Location="{Binding Location}"
                              Address="{Binding Address}"
                              Label="{Binding Description}" />
                </DataTemplate>    
            </maps:Map.ItemTemplate>
        </maps:Map>
        ...
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

It works well. And this is [the sample by official](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/7.0/UserInterface/Views/Map).